# DBF - encoding cp1250

Tags: python, database, encoding, anaconda, dbf

I have dbf database encoded in cp1250 and I am reading this database using folowing code:

```
import csv
from dbfpy import dbf
import os
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
if filename.endswith('.dbf'):
    print "Converting %s to csv" % filename
    csv_fn = filename[:-4]+ ".csv"
    with open(csv_fn,'wb') as csvfile:
        in_db = dbf.Dbf(filename)
        out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)
        names = []
        for field in in_db.header.fields:
            names.append(field.name)
        #out_csv.writerow(names)
        for rec in in_db:
            out_csv.writerow(rec.fieldData)
        in_db.close()
        print "Done..."
else:
  print "Filename does not end with .dbf"
```

Problem is, that final csv file is wrong. Encoding of the file is ANSI and some characters are corrupted. I would like to ask you, if you can help me how to read dbf file correctly.

**EDIT 1**

I tried different code from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpledbf/0.2.4, there is some error.

Source 2:

```
from simpledbf import Dbf5
import os
import sys

dbf = Dbf5('test.dbf', codec='cp1250');
dbf.to_csv('junk.csv');
```

Output:

```
python program2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program2.py", line 5, in <module>
    dbf = Dbf5('test.dbf', codec='cp1250');
  File "D:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\simpledbf\simpledbf.py",      line 557, in __init__
    assert terminator == b'\r'
```

AssertionError

I really don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [my dbf library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf):

```
import dbf
with dbf.Table('test.dbf') as table:
    dbf.export(table, 'junk.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote simpledbf. The line that is causing you problems was from some testing I was doing when developing the module. First of all, you might want to update your installation, as 0.2.6 is the most recent. Then you can try removing that particular line (#557) from the file "D:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\simpledbf\simpledbf.py". If that doesn't work, you can ping me at the [GitHub repo for simpledbf](https://github.com/rnelsonchem/simpledbf), or you could try Ethan's suggestion for the dbf module.

Comment: It works too. Thanks for answer. :) There is just error on empty field."ValueError: Column type "" not yet supported."

Answer (score 0):

You can decode and encode as necessary. `dbfpy` assumes strings are `utf8` encoded, so you can decode as it isn't that encoding and then encode again with the right encoding.

```
import csv
from dbfpy import dbf
import os
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
if filename.endswith('.dbf'):
    print "Converting %s to csv" % filename
    csv_fn = filename[:-4]+ ".csv"
    with open(csv_fn,'wb') as csvfile:
        in_db = dbf.Dbf(filename)
        out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)
        names = []
        for field in in_db.header.fields:
            names.append(field.name)
        #out_csv.writerow(names)
        for rec in in_db:
            row = [i.decode('utf8').encode('cp1250') if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in rec.fieldData]
            out_csv.writerow(rec.fieldData)
        in_db.close()
        print "Done..."
else:
  print "Filename does not end with .dbf"
```